# OOP form validator implementing length rules

Tags: php, oop

So i have a pretty basic oop form validator class. but i'm having hard time trying to implement max_length and min_length rules. my rules work like this rule1|rule2 etc so the | separates between the rules. i'm trying to do this required|max_length,60|min_length,10. `

```
public function validate($field,$value,$rules)
   {
     $field = ucfirst($field);
     $rules = explode('|',$rules);
     foreach($rules as $rule)
     {
        switch($rule)
         {
            case 'required':
                $this->shouldBeRequired($field, $value);
                break;
            case 'string':
                $this->shouldBeString($field,$value);
                break;
            case 'email':
                $this->shouldBeEmail($field, $value);
                break;
            case 'number':
                $this->shouldBeNumber($field,$value);
            default:
                throw new ErrorException("$rule doesn't exist");
        }
     }
   }`
```

and i have no idea how to add max_length and min_length case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your rule into its parts separated by `,`:

```php
public function validate($field,$value,$rules)
{
     $field = ucfirst($field);
     $rules = explode('|',$rules);
     foreach($rules as $rule)
     {

       $ruleParts = explode(",", $rule);
        switch($ruleParts[0])
         {
            case 'required':
                $this->shouldBeRequired($field, $value);
                break;
            case 'string':
                $this->shouldBeString($field,$value);
                break;
            case 'email':
                $this->shouldBeEmail($field, $value);
                break;
            case 'number':
                $this->shouldBeNumber($field,$value);
                break; // You forgot this one!
            case 'min-length':
                if (isset($ruleParts[1]) && is_numeric($ruleParts[1]))
                    $this->restrictMinLength($ruleParts[1]);
                else
                    //Parameter forgotten or invalid
                break;
            default:
                throw new ErrorException("$rule doesn't exist");
        }
     }
   }
```

For max-length, it's the same.

Btw, you forgot one `break` as shown commented inline

Comment: will this work with min-length,3|max-length,50? i mean we only have $ruleParts[1].

Comment: Each rule gets split into its own array: `ruleParts[0]` is the rulename, `ruleParts[1]` is the first parameter of each rule, so yes, it would work. You could now even use more than 1 parameter for each rule, such as `size,2,6`. `ruleParts[0]` would be `size`, `ruleParts[1]` would be `2`, `ruleParts[2]` would be `6`

Answer (score 1):

notice that you should implement the new two functions : `shouldBeLessThan` and `shouldBeGreaterThan`

```
public function validate($field,$value,$rules)
{
    $field = ucfirst($field);
    $rules = explode('|',$rules);
    foreach($rules as $rule)
    {
        $rule = explode(',', $rule);
        switch($rule[0])
        {
            case 'required':
                $this->shouldBeRequired($field, $value);
                break;
            case 'string':
                $this->shouldBeString($field,$value);
                break;
            case 'email':
                $this->shouldBeEmail($field, $value);
                break;
            case 'number':
                $this->shouldBeNumber($field,$value);
                break;
            case 'max_length':
                $this->shouldBeLessThan($field, $value, $rule[1]);
                break;
            case 'min_length':
                $this->shouldBeGreaterThan($field, $value, $rule[1]);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ErrorException("$rule doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```